# Are firestore server timestamps the same for multiple writes in a transaction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unsure if server timestamps will be the same for two document writes in a transaction. I'm assuming they won't be (as they are separate writes), but I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, and figured it's possible they're the same due to way they're batched.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

With Firestore, a server timestamp is taken once at the moment a query is received and reused as many times as the server timestamp token appears in the request.  This means all documents that reference the token in a transaction will all get the same timestamp.

It's the same for security rules. During the evaluation of a rule, the value of [`request.time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) is the same throughout the evaluation so you can check that every occurrence of a timestamp in every written document was specified exactly as a server timestamp.